# How to change the Properties.store() divider symbol from "=" to ":"?

Tags: java, properties, divider

I recently found out about `java.util.Properties`, which allows me to write and read from a config without writing my own function for it.

I was excited since it is so easy to use, but later noticed a flaw when I stored the modified config file.

Here is my code, quite simple for now:

```
FileWriter writer = null;
Properties configFile = new Properties();
configFile.load(ReadFileTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.txt"));

String screenwidth = configFile.getProperty("screenwidth");
String screenheight = configFile.getProperty("screenheight");
System.out.println(screenwidth);
System.out.println(screenheight);
configFile.setProperty("screenwidth", "1024");
configFile.setProperty("screenheight", "600");
try {
    writer = new FileWriter("config.txt" );
    configFile.store(writer, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

The problem I noticed was that the config file I try to edit is stored like this:

```
foo: bar
bar: foo
foobar: barfoo
```

However, the output after `properties.store(writer, null)` is this:

```
foo=bar
bar=foo
foobar=barfoo
```

The config file I edit is not for my program, it is for an other application that needs the config file to be in the format shown above with `:` as divider or else it will reset the configuration to default.

Does anybody know how to easily change this?

I searched through the first 5 Google pages now but found noone with a similar problem.
I also checked the Javadoc and found no function that allows me to change it without writing a class for myself.
I would like to use `Properties` for now since it is there and quite easy to use.
I also got the idea of just replacing all `=` with `:` after I saved the file but maybe someone got a better suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a tool that isn't designed for the task - don't use `Properties` here.  Instead, I'd just write your own - should be easy enough.

You can still use a `Properties` instance as your "store", but don't use it for serializing the properties to text.  Instead, just use a `FileWriter`, iterate through the properties, and write the lines yourself - as `key + ": " + value`.

Comment: That is quite a good idea, I will just use Properties to read the file and a FileWriter to store it back, thank you will try it now.

Comment: However, do check out how Properties.saveConvert() and loadConvert() escape special characters.  This could be a significant issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

New idea here

*Your comment about converting the = to : got me thinking*: Properties.store() writes to a Stream.  You could use an in-memory ByteArrayOutputStream, convert as appropriate in memory *before* you write to a file, then write the file.  Likewise for Properties.load().  Or you could insert FilterXXXs instead.  (I'd probably do it in memory).

---

I was looking into how hard it would be to subclass.  It's nearly impossible.  :-(

If you look at the source code for Properties, (I'm looking at Java 6) store() calls store0().  Now, unfortunately, store0 is private, not protected, and the "=" is given as a magic constant, not something read from a property.  And it calls another private method called saveConvert() that also has a lot of magic constants.

Overall, I rate this code as D- quality.  It breaks almost all the rules of good code and good style.

But, it's open source, so, theoretically, you could copy and paste (and improve!) a bunch of code into your own BetterProperties class.